# Как прекратить остановку программы

Tags: java

Есть некий код, который выполняется, и программа завершается. Как сделать так, чтобы программа не завершала свое действие, пока через некоторое время не выполнится следующий код?

Comment: Шедуль через потоки

Comment: я новичек в этом деле, можно как то понятнее))

Comment: к примеру используем ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно использовать

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
```

Используя многопоточность и некий пул-потоков который вы будете организовывать.

Почитайте на эту тему очень много примеров и разных алгоритмов и реализаций в целом.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final class RunnableWrapper implements Runnable
{
    private final Runnable _r;

    public RunnableWrapper(final Runnable r)
    {
        _r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public final void run()
    {
        try
        {
            _r.run();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            log.error("Unhandeled exception", e);
            final Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            final UncaughtExceptionHandler h = t.getUncaughtExceptionHandler();
            if (h != null)
                h.uncaughtException(t, e);
        }
    }
}
```

и собственно инициаллизация действия посредством ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

```
public static long validateDelay(long delay)
{
    if (delay < 0)
        delay = 0;
    else if (delay > MAX_DELAY)
        delay = MAX_DELAY;
    return delay;
}

public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable r, long delay)
{
    try
    {
        delay = validateDelay(delay);
        return _generalScheduledThreadPool.schedule(new RunnableWrapper(r), delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    catch (RejectedExecutionException e)
    {
        return null; /* shutdown, ignore */
    }
}
```